Перенести проект Django с WSGI + основной сервере Apache2 на Django с ASGI + Daphne основной сервер + Apache2 обратный прокси
Проект Django, размещен на Apache2 - работает отлично. Появилась необходимость внедрения чата на сайт. После "гугления" понял, что Django Channels + Daphne мой выбор, при этом, если я правильно понял, Daphne должен стать основным сервером, а текущий Apache2 должен стать обратным прокси сервером.
Для начала я добавил все настройки ASGI по доке Channels в проект, далее установил Reddis, все хорошо, сейчас он работает и слушает 6379 порт, Apache2 443 и 80 (с redirect на 443). Далее, если я правильно понял, мне нужно установить daphne с запустить с него ASGI, но на этом месте загвоздка, пытаюсь запихнуть запуск Daphne в сервис:
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon for Django
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=sudo
WorkingDirectory: /path/to/myproject
ExecStart=daphne nameProject.asgi:application --port 80 --bind myPort -v2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Но сервис не в какую не запускается, выдает ошибку:
daphne[115677]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nameProject'

Если я запускаю команду из терминала:
sudo daphne nameProject.asgi:application --port 80 --bind myPort -v2

Он запускается без проблем, правда без static файлов, но это другой вопрос. И если я правильно понял из доки, после запуска Daphne - можно будет добавлять в проект WebSoсket код. Помогите запустить Daphne.
p.s. Daphne проинсталлен не в venv, а на локальный python.

«Daphne проинсталлен не в venv» — ну значит в этом и ошибка видимо
